# Error in sql sintaxis near the use SELECT, code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR', errno: 1064

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, node-mysql

I 'm having an error in an sql query. I get the therror: code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
errno: 1064.

I tried copying and pasting it directly to the database and it worked perfectly but when I run it on my nodejs server usign mysql i get the error. The query is:

```
SELECT  ER.id_entidad as companyid, E.nombre as name, ER.posicion as position, E.url_imagen as url,ER.created
FROM
entidad_red ER, cajero C, red R, entidad E
WHERE E.id_red = R.id_red AND C.id_red = E.id_red AND E.id_entidad = ER.id_entidad AND C.Serial = 'id'
```

And the sqlMessage is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'SELECT  ER.id_entidad as companyid, E.nombre as name, ER.posicion as position, \' at line
>   1'.

Thanks for the help

This is how I execute the query:

```
const dbConnection = mysql.createConnection(config);

app.get('/kioskcompanies', middleware.checkToken, function(req, res){
        var serial = req.query.kioskid;
        var sql = "SELECT  ER.id_entidad as companyid, E.nombre as name, ER.posicion as position, E.url_imagen as url,ER.created " +
        "FROM entidad_red ER, cajero C, red R, entidad E " +
        "WHERE " +
        "E.id_red = R.id_red " +
        "AND C.id_red = E.id_red " +
        "AND E.id_entidad = ER.id_entidad " +
        "AND C.Serial = '" + serial + "'";
        console.log(sql)
        dbConnection.query(sql, (err, result) => {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                res.status(200).json({
                    status:'error',
                    code:"1",
                    msg:'Error consultando la BD',
                })
            }
            else if(result.length === 0){
                res.status(200).json({
                    status:'error',
                    code:"3",
                    msg:'Entidad de recaudo no existe.',
                })
            }
            else{
                res.status(200).json({
                    status:'error',
                    code:'0',
                    companies:result,
                    msg:'Consulta correcta'
                })
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: This function is similar to many others I have, basically only the query changes. Although the other ones work perfectly but this one has this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Apparently between de Select and the rows I had two spaces and mysql-node doesn't work with that. PhpMyAdmin does execute the query but Node doesn't.